# Logical Cell Array Indexing

Tags: matlab

I have a two dimensional array of cells and a two dimensional logical which is the same size. 
I would like to create a new array of cells by selecting cell elements based on the logicals.

I am able to do this using a loop:

```
#allbins - array of 1s and 0s to select items for groupA
#selectionvalues - cell array 

for n=1:size(allbins,1)
      groupA = selectionvalues(1,logical(allbins(n,:)))
end
```

This performs the task.

How could I perform this without a loop?

Comment: Why do you want to do it without a loop?

Comment: It seems a bit wasteful to iterate through the cell array and logical array by row.